# How could I implement a divided bar visualization in SVG with rounded corners?

Tags: svg

I want to implement a visualization in SVG that is basically a bar that is split among several colors. Kind of like what this HTML+CSS snippet produces.

```css
#wholeThing {
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 30px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#wholeThing div {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
}

#foo {
  background: red;
  width: 10px;
}

#bar {
  background: green;
  width: 10px;
}

#baz {
  background: blue;
  width: 270px;
}
```

```html
<div id='wholeThing'>
  <div id='foo'></div>
  <div id='bar'></div>
  <div id='baz'></div>
  <div id='quux'></div>
</div>
```

It must be in SVG because the visualization will be appended to other SVG elements, and I do not want to use `foreignObject`.

I tried inserting smaller rects into one SVG element, ie

```
<svg>
  <rect> ...
  <rect> ...
  <rect> ...
</svg>
```

but I can't see how I could implement rounded corners with this approach. One rounded corner could encompass several smaller rects as in my example.

Also, the svg element does not heed a border-radius CSS property.

Maybe I could make this visualization using a multi-colored stroke of a line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of ways you could do it.

- using a `<clipPath>`
- using a `<mask>`
- using a `<linearGradient>`

For example, using a gradient:

```html
<svg>
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="graph1">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="red"/>
      <stop offset="20%" stop-color="red"/>
      <stop offset="20%" stop-color="orange"/>
      <stop offset="70%" stop-color="orange"/>
      <stop offset="70%" stop-color="green"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
    
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="300" height="50" rx="10" ry="10" fill="url(#graph1)"/>
</svg>
```